# Displaylink adapter not showing full resolution options available in 18.04

Tags: graphics, multiple-monitors, suspend, display-resolution, displaylink

When I upgraded from 16.04 -> 18.04 the monitor attached to my displaylink adapter stopped outputting in 1080p. The only options available for it now are 1024x768 and 800x600. Also, I cannot put the computer to sleep anymore. Whenever I do I see an error that the adapter leaked and it fails to sleep. I also posted in displaylink forum [here](https://www.displaylink.org/forum/showthread.php?t=66294) but have not gotten any response. I also tried running [this](https://github.com/AdnanHodzic/displaylink-debian) but did not work for me either. Still only getting the lower resolution options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by changing the cable from HDMI to display port using the displaylink adapter. The displaylink adapter supports both cables using the appropriate adapter.